# Form Submit Input > Page opens in new window

Tags: jquery, html

I have a website, I've created with a 'Custom Search' functionality. I set it up so this 'Search Field Screen' (Where the user enters in a search) opens up at click with a fancybox iframe.

It looks fantastic, *EXCEPT* - when the users 'Submits' the form - or enters their custom search and continues to the next screen. The results screen pulls in within the iframe box still (AH!). It needs to pull up normally in the browser in place of the search window.

I've tried adding `target="_parent"`

**EG:**

```
<INPUT type="submit" target="_parent" name="search" value="Search" border="0" style="cursor:pointer;" class="searchbtn"></form>
```

**I guess ultimately how do you submit within an a iframe-fancybox, with the next page or results, clearing the fancybox and loading in place within the same window?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use the target attribute in the **form tag** not in the input tag.

But the target attribute has been depecated, so you can use the formtarget="_parent" attribute for the **Submit button**.

Comment: Thanks - I'm still not having luck, is that the actual syntax to use; with no spaces? ' formtarget="_parent" '?

Comment: AH - well. The best I get I suppose; and I cannot delete the Question. Cheers homie.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: target="_self". May it work.